# Can't browse directly to article alias

Tags: joomla-3.x, alias

I have an article that I want to link to directly using html rather than create a menu item that links to it. I was able to do this in Drupal but when I try the same thing in Joomla it doesn't seem to work, i.e. when I type in `www.mysite.com/legal-notice` I get a 404 error. If I add the article as a menu item then I can do this, but then I notice that the menu item has an alias as well, which is the same, so maybe it is just that that I am navigating to rather than the article alias.

Is this just something you can't do in Joomla? Surely not? I have SEF urls turned on, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no simple way to achieve what you want. When you create a menu item, your link goes to the menu item alias, not to the article alias.

So you need a menu item for your article, but you don't have to **show** the menu item. This can be achieved in two ways:

**Hidden menu**

1. Create a new menu (**Menus** → **Manage** → **Add New Menu**). Call it anything you want, e.g. "Hidden menu".
2. Create a menu item linking to your article, and set the alias to what you want the URL to be, like `legal-notice`.
3. That's it, you can now view your article at `www.mysite.com/legal-notice`, even if the menu isn't displayed anywhere on your website.

**Invisible menu item**

1. Create a menu item in your main menu, linking to your article, and set the alias to what you want the URL to be, like `legal-notice`.
2. In the "Link Type" tab, set "Display in Menu" to **No**. This will hide your menu item.

   [image: Display in Menu]
3. That's it, you can now view your article at `www.mysite.com/legal-notice`, even if the menu item isn't displayed anywhere on your website.

Comment: The first method worked perfectly. Thank you kindly. Seems obvious once you pointed it out. The second method wouldn't work for me as I didn't have the Display in Menu option under Link Type. Add Menu Title is the last option showing there.

Comment: @Alistair67 The "Display in Menu" feature was implemented recently, so you're probably not running the latest version of Joomla. Please upgrade in order to keep your site safe :)

Comment: I'd love to update the site but the updates won't take. Keep getting an `The archive file is corrupt, truncated or archive parts are missing` error. Been trying the solutions found online, tmp folder is writable for example and I can put files in it with Filezilla using the same credentials I've given to Joomla when using the update via FTP option, but no joy. Any suggestions?

Comment: Let me update. I can put files in with Filezilla but according to Joomla the log and tmp folders are unwriteable, I now discover from Site Information. However, the site is on Azure and it seems I can't change folder permissions. Grrrr.